# Why does my input not maintain the checked state even when I manually set the input to checked?

Tags: css

#### Edit 1

As requested, here is the `setRating(value, questionId)` function.
When it appeared that the inputs weren't being checked because I'm not clicking on them directly, I wrote this function to force the update, setting the input to checked.

```
function setRating(value, questionId) {
    const identifier = `${questionId}_${value}`
    const radioInput = document.querySelector(`input#rating_${identifier}`)
    radioInput.checked = true
}
```

#### Question

My SCSS builds some styles for my 0-5 rating system with a red "N/A" item indicating no rating.

The idea is that if I select a 3-star rating, stars 1 & 2 should highlight along with star 3. Highlighted stars turn gold while the N/A item highlights red.

Functionally this all works insofar as the data is pushed to my API correctly based on selected ratings, however the styling fails to maintain highlight.

This is to say that when I move the mouse cursor away from the selected rating element (no matter what it is), the highlighting disappears and all rating elements for the question turn grey again.

I feel like I'm missing something so here's my SCSS and following is the markup for a single question. I usually have multiple questions on a page (in case that's relevant).

As far as I can tell, everything should be set to distinguish the N/A item from the rating stars and maintain highlighting so I'm really at a loss here. Not at all sure how to fix this.

[Codepen showing the behavior](https://codepen.io/ortund/pen/bGJEYav?editors=1100)

#### SCSS

```
.ratings {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row-reverse;
    justify-content: center;

    input {
        display: none;

        &.na:checked + label::before {
            content: "N/A";
            color: red;
            font-size: 24px;
            padding: 0 5px;
            transition: 300ms ease all;
        }

        &:checked + label::before {
            color: gold;
        }
    }

    label {
        cursor: pointer;

        &::before {
            content: "\2605";
            color: grey;
            font-size: 24px;
            padding: 0 5px;
            transition: 300ms ease all;
        }

        &:hover::before {
            color: gold;
        }
    }

    input:not(.na):checked + label::before {
        content: "\2605";
        color: gold;
    }

    label.active:not(.na) {
        color: gold;
    }
    label.na.active {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

#### Markup

```
<div id="feedbackFormContainer" class="container">
  <section class="mb-3 w-100 section" data-section-id="1">
    <input type="hidden" id="token" name="token" value="eyJCb29raW5nSWQiOjE4NzA2LCJNZW1iZXJJZCI6ODg5MX0=">
    <input type="hidden" id="sectionId" name="sectionId" value="1">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header text-center">
        <p><span id="sectionCounter" class="d-none">1</span>Booking and Pre-Assessment</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body w-100">
        <div class="questionContainer border border-secondary rounded">
          <input type="hidden" name="BookingId" id="BookingId" value="18706">
          <div class="questions">

            <div class="question1">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="mt-2 mr-3 flex-fill" style="padding-left:10px;font-size:1em;">Was the booking process easy and convenient?</div>
                <div class="ratings ml-3 border-left" data-questionid="1">

                  <input type="radio" value="5" name="rating1" id="rating_1_5">
                  <label name="label_1_5" id="label_1_5" for="rating1_5" onclick="setRating(5, 1)"></label>

                  <input type="radio" value="4" name="rating1" id="rating_1_4">
                  <label name="label_1_4" id="label_1_4" for="rating1_4" onclick="setRating(4, 1)"></label>

                  <input type="radio" value="3" name="rating1" id="rating_1_3">
                  <label name="label_1_3" id="label_1_3" for="rating1_3" onclick="setRating(3, 1)"></label>

                  <input type="radio" value="2" name="rating1" id="rating_1_2">
                  <label name="label_1_2" id="label_1_2" for="rating1_2" onclick="setRating(2, 1)"></label>

                  <input type="radio" value="1" name="rating1" id="rating_1_1">
                  <label name="label_1_1" id="label_1_1" for="rating1_1" onclick="setRating(1, 1)"></label>

                  <input type="radio" value="0" name="rating1" id="rating_1_0" class="na">
                  <label name="label_1_0" id="label_1_0" class="na active" for="rating1_0" onclick="setRating(0, 1)"></label>

                </div>
              </div>
              <textarea class="comment w-100 form-control" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Any comments?" data-questionid="1"></textarea>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <p>Section 1 of 15.</p>

        <button id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary mt-3" onclick="saveFeedback();"><i class="spinner fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin text-white d-none mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

#### Full code (collated from the code posted elsewhere in this question):

```js
function setRating(value, questionId) {
  const identifier = `${questionId}_${value}`
  const radioInput = document.querySelector(`input#rating_${identifier}`)
  radioInput.checked = true
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.ratings {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ratings input.na {
  display: none;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ratings input.na:checked~label.na::before {
  color: red;
}

.ratings label.na::before {
  content: "N/A";
  color: grey;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  transition: 300ms ease all;
}

.ratings label.na:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ratings label.na:hover::before {
  color: red;
}

.ratings label.na:hover~label.na::before {
  color: red;
}

.ratings input:not(.na) {
  display: none;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ratings input:not(.na):checked~label:not(.na)::before {
  color: gold;
}

.ratings label:not(.na)::before {
  content: "★";
  color: grey;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  transition: 300ms ease all;
}

.ratings label:not(.na):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ratings label:not(.na):hover::before {
  color: gold;
}

.ratings label:not(.na):hover~label:not(.na)::before {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="feedbackFormContainer" class="container">
  <section class="mb-3 w-100 section" data-section-id="1">
    <input type="hidden" id="token" name="token" value="eyJCb29raW5nSWQiOjE4NzA2LCJNZW1iZXJJZCI6ODg5MX0=">
    <input type="hidden" id="sectionId" name="sectionId" value="1">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header text-center">
        <p><span id="sectionCounter" class="d-none">1</span>Booking and Pre-Assessment</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body w-100">
        <div class="questionContainer border border-secondary rounded">
          <input type="hidden" name="BookingId" id="BookingId" value="18706">
          <div class="questions">

            <div class="question1">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="mt-2 mr-3 flex-fill" style="padding-left:10px;font-size:1em;">Was the booking process easy and convenient?</div>
                <div class="ratings ml-3 border-left" data-questionid="1">

                  <input type="radio" value="5" name="rating1" id="rating_1_5">
                  <label name="label_1_5" id="label_1_5" for="rating1_5" onclick="setRating(5, 1)"></label>

                  <input type="radio" value="4" name="rating1" id="rating_1_4">
                  <label name="label_1_4" id="label_1_4" for="rating1_4" onclick="setRating(4, 1)"></label>

                  <input type="radio" value="3" name="rating1" id="rating_1_3">
                  <label name="label_1_3" id="label_1_3" for="rating1_3" onclick="setRating(3, 1)"></label>

                  <input type="radio" value="2" name="rating1" id="rating_1_2">
                  <label name="label_1_2" id="label_1_2" for="rating1_2" onclick="setRating(2, 1)"></label>

                  <input type="radio" value="1" name="rating1" id="rating_1_1">
                  <label name="label_1_1" id="label_1_1" for="rating1_1" onclick="setRating(1, 1)"></label>

                  <input type="radio" value="0" name="rating1" id="rating_1_0" class="na">
                  <label name="label_1_0" id="label_1_0" class="na active" for="rating1_0" onclick="setRating(0, 1)"></label>

                </div>
              </div>
              <textarea class="comment w-100 form-control" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Any comments?" data-questionid="1"></textarea>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <p>Section 1 of 15.</p>

        <button id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary mt-3" onclick="saveFeedback();"><i class="spinner fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin text-white d-none mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show also the Javascript. There is some weird behavior when selecting say 4 stars on the second question, the first question 5 stars go down to 4. And make the code into a runnable snippet within the question so it's useful to future readers.

Comment: `onclick="setRating(5, 1)"` - a), you neglected us to show what that function actually does, and b), in the codepen you are not passing a second parameter, even though you are using _multiple_ different rating elements in there as well ...?

Comment: It's possible in my work troubleshooting the issue, I forgot to update the codepen, however all the `setRating(value, questionId)` updates seem to be there, although the parameters are named differently. Nevertheless I've included the function in an edit on the question @AHaworth @CBroe

Comment: I've edited your question to convert your various posted pieces of code into a runnable demo - as A Haworth asked you to do, earlier - I did, however, compile the SCSS to CSS for purposes of the demo. Please edit if you think I've made errors, or introduced problems.

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks for that. I wanted to do it as a snippet but I couldn't work out how; I didn't see any option for it

Answer (score 0):

The SCSS in the [codepen link](https://codepen.io/ortund/pen/bGJEYav?editors=1100) works.

It would seem I got cached and something the site was not giving me the latest updates to the code.

Here's what worked; the following code correctly manages checked and hover states of the elements and labels.

```
.ratings {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row-reverse;
    justify-content: center;

    input.na {
        display: none;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        visibility: hidden;

        &:checked ~ label.na::before {
            color: red;
        }
    }

    label.na {
        &::before {
            content: "N/A";
            color: grey;
            font-size: 24px;
            padding: 0 5px;
            transition: 300ms ease all;
        }

        &:hover {
            cursor: pointer;

            &::before {
                color: red;
            }

            ~ label.na::before {
                color: red;
            }
        }
    }

    input:not(.na) {
        display: none;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        visibility: hidden;

        &:checked ~ label:not(.na)::before {
            color: gold;
        }
    }

    label:not(.na) {
        &::before {
            content: "\2605";
            color: grey;
            font-size: 24px;
            padding: 0 5px;
            transition: 300ms ease all;
        }

        &:hover {
            cursor: pointer;

            &::before {
                color: gold;
            }

            ~ label:not(.na)::before {
                color: gold;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following javascript may not be necessary but is used to force the radio buttons into a `checked` state so that the checked ones can be identified later at form submission.

```
function setRating(v, questionId) {
    const radioInput = document.querySelector(`input#rating_${questionId}_${v}`)
    radioInput.checked = true
}
```

###### Getting the page to load the correct code:

1. Remove SCSS compilations from your project
2. Remove the files for previous compilations
3. Create a new SCSS file with a unique file name and compile it to your project
4. Update `<link src="..."` values to target the new stylesheet

This will force the page to download and use the corrected code (cache killer and reloading out of cache didn't have any effect).